# jQuery event listener for Apple dictation / speech-to-text

Tags: jquery, google-maps, listener, speech-to-text, dictation

Is there some kind of jQuery listener for Apple dictation? How to get an alert when the user used Apple dictation on a textbox?
I couldn't try different speech-to-text apps but I guess the problem and the solution are the same for all of them.

My problem: I am using the Google Maps API with a search box to look for cities. Everything works perfectly but when entering the text by speaking no suggestions are made and therefore the user cannot look for cities.
I think the best solution would be to just check when someone entered text with an speech-to-text app and then do the usual, like

```
$("#address").XXX(XXX, function() { the usual });
```

*`#address` is the textbox*